# Call create action through a form with a variable from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, models, model-associations

Two of the models I have in the rails 4 app are the following:

```
class Council < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :alternatives
    ...
end

class Alternative < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :council
    ...
end
```

I am rendering an Alternative form that allows me to create a new Alternative object from a Council's show view:

#### councils/show.html.erb

```
<%= render 'alternatives/form' %>
```

#### alternatives/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@alternative) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
      <div>
        <%= f.text_field :title, :placeholder => 'Provide your alternative', autofocus: true, class:"form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div>
        <%= f.text_area :more_info, :placeholder => 'Describe your alternative', autofocus: true, class:"form-control", rows: '4' %>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div>
      <%= f.submit 'Submit the alternative!', class:"btn btn-success"  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

At that point, I want to associate the Alternative object with the specific Council object from the show view, like the code below, but the variable @council is not defined:

#### controllers/alternatives_controller.rb

```
class AlternativesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_alternative, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @alternative = Alternative.new(alternative_params)
    @alternative.council = @council
  end

  private

    def set_alternative
      @alternative = Alternative.find(params[:id])
    end

    def alternative_params
      params.require(:alternative).permit(:title, :more_info)
    end
end
```

That will allow me to show all the alternatives associated with a certain Council object:

#### councils/show.html.erb

```
...
<% @council.alternatives.each do |alternative| %>
    <%= alternative.title %>
    <%= alternative.more_info %>
<% end %>
...
```

I've carefully reviewed the Ruby on Rails Guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) but clearly I am missing something. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several options for you:

---

**Nested**

I've not tested this, but you *could* use multiple objects in your `form_for` helper:

```
#app/views/councils/show.html.erb
<%= form_for [@council, @alternative] do |f| %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

This will send your request through to the `council_alternatives_path` (you can change it), and provide you with `params[:council_id]` and `params[:id]`

You could set your routes like this to get it to work:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :councils do
   resources :alternatives, only: [:create]
end
```

This will be a little hacky I think (as it's meant for forms with `nested` attributes), but it's still a viable way to achieve what you want

---

**Nested Attributes**

The other option is to use the [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) directive in your model. This will be overkill for what you need I think, but could help:

```
#app/models/council.rb
Class Council < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :alternatives
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :alternatives
end

#app/models/alternative.rb
Class Alternative < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :council
end
```

This will allow you to use the `@council` object to save any new `Alternative` objects you need:

```
#app/controllers/councils_controller.rb
Class CouncilsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @council = Council.find params[:id]
      @council.alternatives.build
   end

   def update
      @council = Council.find params[:id]
      @council.update(council_params)
   end

   private

   def council_params
      params.require(:council).permit(alterantives_attributes: [:alternatives, :attributes])
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use the following form code:

```
#app/views/councils/show.html.erb
<%= form_for @council do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :alternatives do |a| %>
      <%= a.text_field :your_info %>
   <% end %>
   <% f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved the issue. I will go for the first alternative you provided, it makes more sense in the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

What do your `routes.rb` look like? In this case, it seems like the easiest thing would be to have your `alternative` nested under your `council` routes, so something like this:

resources :councils do
  resources :alternatives
end

In which case, in your `alternatives_controller.rb` in the create action, you have to just set the `@council` object from the parameters.

ie.

```
  def create
    @council = Council.find(params[:council_id])
    @alternative = Alternative.new(alternative_params)
    @alternative.council = @council
    @alternative.save
  end
```

Comment: Thanks! I will add to what you provided: `<%= form_for [@council, @alternative] do |f| %>` as @RichPeck stated, that will complete the solution. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would nest it in the routes as derekyau stated above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25109545/3105349)

But you could also use a hidden field in the form to pass through the council id i.e.

```
<%= hidden_field :council_id, @council.id %>
```

Then in the controller you can access it through the params

```
@council = Council.find(params[:alternative][:council_id])
```

or add it to your alternative params to assign it automatically

```
def alternative_params
  params.require(:alternative).permit(:title, :more_info, :council_id)
end
```

But again, making it a nested route is the cleaner and preferred solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as you stated, nested routes is the best way to go in that case.